# As an immortal, how can I find someone to run my kingdom when I get bored?

Tags: government, immortality

It really wasn't all that hard, taking over the kingdom. I had a few hundred years to amass my fortunes, and once the nobility saw through my charade of strikingly similar genes passed from son to son, it actually got easier! I wish I'd've come out to them hundreds of years ago so they'd treat me with the respect I deserve.

Anyway, it's been fun. My subjects really like what I've done with the place, my armies are strong and well fed, and advances in technology are finally letting people get out of the fields and focus on furthering goals of science and medicine.

But I'm a little bored. First, I really don't want to limit myself to a single kingdom. I'm still a few hundred years away from any sort of instant communications that would allow me to truly have a world empire, but I'd love to start with at least just this continent. But without being able to communicate back home quickly, I am worried whoever I choose to run my kingdom will let it fall apart while I'm gone. Further, once I finally do take over the continent (and the world) I need a process in place that allows me to have the freedom I deserve for taking over the while without losing my position of power.

Because I have such a high approval rating among my subjects, I'm thinking I could have some sort of democratic election. But if my subjects pick someone who is ultimately bad for the kingdom (not that it would happen, but you never know,) I need a solid escape valve.

If it helps, I do have a vague notion of things that haven't been invented yet, including things from 1300 AD (which is about present day) and about 1000 years after that. You should totally see what's in store for you in 2128, it will blow your mind!* But I don't have specifics enough to really recreate them from scratch. I'd be able to have a meaningful conversation with your typical college graduate about notions of government, economics, the scientific method, and the various inventions over the years.

#### What system can I use to find someone to rule my kingdom(s) that will 1) last for hundreds or thousands of years 2) give me the freedom to conquer the rest of the world and 3) keep my people happy?

<sub>* Literally, every human on the bionet got their memory wiped. Luckily a few engineers were offline at the time and restored everyone from backup. *phew*</sub>

Comment: It's not like you want to remove yourself completely from ruling (like King Lear), you only want to go to war commanding your armies and make sure that you will be no Richard the Lionheart and your homeland will be in good care?

Comment: I would like the freedom to leave for, let's say, 20 years at a time with zero input.

Comment: I apologize, but this isn't a world-building question.  It's a story-building question.  A world-building question is relevant regardless what individual is in charge.  A story-building question is dependent on exactly what individual is in charge.

Comment: Why would you care? You're immortal, so why you worry about what some mortal might do to the place while you're away? Isn't this, for example, like a present-day mortal worrying about what their dog gets up to while they're at work? It might even be fun (for you) to see what kind of havoc could be caused in your absence. Give you something to do with that boredom on your return!

Comment: What does immortal mean?  Can death by accident occur?

Comment: You might want to look into the british parliament, Technically the parliament serves at the pleasure of the queen.

Comment: The answer to these questions is surprisingly subjective.  What do you want your kingdom to do while you're gone?  As the immortal leader, your personal opinions of what the kingdom actually needs to look like when you return have complete domination over what structures need to be put in place.

Comment: @JBH I disagree - this system is going to be implemented across every kingdom I conquer, and is fundamentally going to change the world.

Comment: Per our [help page](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): questions are welcomed "as long as they are not about: Actions of individual characters, rather than elements of the world they inhabit."  Your question is off-topic.

Comment: @JBH I think I see what you're getting at, but I don't think it's about it talking about an individual. The framing device is fine and can be read as a series of parameters like immortal ruler, known to public, popular, system should survive decades-long holidays etc. I think the core issue comes from the problem statement itself, which reads as 'How can I be Willy Wonka' (which leans well into story-based)

Comment: @JBH When the action of the character is to *decide on a form of government* I'd say it's entirely worldbuilding, not story building.

Comment: @JBH This is actually almost identical in nature to https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/29199/how-would-government-change-if-everyone-died-by-the-age-of-25?rq=1 the only difference is the ruler lives forever instead of dying right away (which, of course is a big difference in terms of the parameter, but not in the nature of the question.) So if this one is to be closed, then so should that one.

Comment: Rules change over time, CorsiKa, and you just pointed to a question over 2 years old.  There are procedures to reopen storybased questions.  Please read through the site's FAQs to discover how.

Answer (score 3):

Make a religion.

It worked for about a millenium for the catholics. Some validated-by-God empires such as the brittish one were ahead of the empiring game for more than a handful centuries. It kinda has been working for about ~1400-1500 for some muslim nations (i.e.: Saudi Arabia, Dubai). The muslims as a whole are fragmented into many kingdoms today but they probably could have been more unified if there wasn't so much meddling from the west during the last few centuries.

Nothing lasts forever. The world might live in relative peace and harmony until <strike>the Fire Nation attacks</strike> some people decide their tea is too heavily taxed and protest by infusing it in a lake. Other groups will soon follow suit. But you may expect around half a millenium of stability.

---

Alternatively you could heed the words of Anatoly Rybakov (usually misattributed to his comrade, Joseph Stalin):

> Death solves all problems — no man, no problem.

Force the saying *"it's a small world after all"* into becoming true. It might be hard depopulating the world, but if timing is good you can make use of the Plague - the one with a capital 'P'. Also combine it with division among peoples, wars, and public policies that result in famine.

Once you've killed most people, nurture a survivor family and proceed with your own religion. Their leader will be to you a kind of Abraham or Noah.

Since the world will be recovering from an early apocalypse, technology will not have reached the leves seen in our own world. It will be easier to come back in the future, with the help of prophets and sages. Anyone who doesn't bow to you will be easier to defeat. And a world such as this is manageable for a single nation - if Alexander the Great did it, so can you.

Comment: Religion ensures that the people are obedient more than government would, true. But in terms of ensuring the successor you choose won't screw up, religion is no different than setting up a government. Only now, you've given your successor absolute power dictated directly from the head of the religion. Should they be corrupt or inept, you've left the people with no recourse to correct the situation.

Answer (score 0):

The best way for an immortal to rule is from behind the scenes, this way you don't need to mess around with the day to day but focus on the big picture.

Why be the king when you can rule the king?

Using your incredible wealth, power and influence, you select who will run the country whilst giving the illusion the people actually control their own destiny.

People who oppose you get crushed.

This means since you don't have to run the day to day, you can step back and follow your own interests but can step back in should it require your personal touch.

Comment: This does not work if he is not present to do that though. He would still need someone pulling the strings for him from the shadows in his scenario.

Comment: You make the assumption you need to pull strings every day. Most people can function day to day without instruction. The only time strings need pulling is on big matters and only if it will go against you.